# Isclosed on Task Object not working correctly

Tags: apex, soql

I am trying to have my tasks be marked as completed with isclosed mapping to true because I need them to appear in an activity history SOQL query.

I am creating a task with the following field mappings and am very confused as to why isclosed is mapping to false. Doesnt "Completed" move isclosed to true.

```
            'Subject' => '[Outreach][Out][Outbound][Gmail] Re: Invoice Purchasing',
            'Description' => 'Running a test',
            'ActivityDate' => Date.today()- 1,
            'Status' => 'Completed',
            'WhatId' => Opportunities[0].Id
```

After I insert the tasks, I am checking the following fields and finding the following results

```
System.debug(tasks[0].Status); --> Completed
System.debug(tasks[0].IsClosed); ---> False
```

Comment: You may like to check what is Completed Status mapped to in your Org. Check the picklist values in Status field.

Comment: It is mapping to closed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`IsClosed` is not true until the record is loaded from the database and the Status is a Closed value. This typically means that you need to use *after* triggers in order to reliably detect when a task has closed. I verified this behavior with the following code:

```
trigger taskTriggerX on Task (before insert, after insert) {
    for(Task record: Trigger.new) {
        if(Trigger.isBefore && record.Subject=='Before' && !record.IsClosed) {
           record.addError('Is Closed is false in before insert');
        }
        if(Trigger.isAfter && record.Subject=='After' && !record.IsClosed) {
           record.addError('Is Closed is false in after insert');
        }
    }
}
```

And the following execute anonymous script:

```
Task[] tasks = new Task[] {
    new Task(Subject='Before',Status='Completed'),
    new Task(Subject='After',Status='Completed')
};
Database.insert(tasks, false);
System.assert(tasks[0].Id == null);
System.assert(tasks[1].Id != null);
```

---

Alternatively, if you're checking the data in memory, you need to remember to query the records back from the database:

```
Task[] tasks = new Task[] {
    new Task(Subject='Before',Status='Completed')
};
Database.insert(tasks, false);
tasks = [SELECT IsClosed FROM Task WHERE Id = :tasks];
System.assert(tasks[0].IsClosed);
```

Comment: Okay - Well now these are not appearing under my activity history for the Whatid and WhoId. Why is this? Is there another requirement?

Comment: @MatthewMetros Is this in Classic or Lightning? Is it a Visualforce page or other custom code? Have you tried reloading the page? The more details you can provide, the better.

Comment: I am creating am creating a batch apex class that goes through Opportunities and their activity histories to find the average number of days between touches for the specific opportunities. I am creating a test class and am getting stumped on getting the completed task to appear in this type of query 'SELECT id (SELECT activitydate FROM activityHistories) FROM Opportunity'

Comment: @MatthewMetros Hmm. So this question was actually an [X-Y Problem](http://xyproblem.info/). You'll want to ask a new question that includes your unit test code and relevant batch code.